# What is the best way to implement group/batch execution within a single web services call?

Tags: web-services

What is the best way to implement group/batch execution within a single web services call?  I have a service that I need to load a bunch of individual records to be processed.   I'd like a tightly coupled interface if possible so that the XSD can validate the request before processing.

Comment: Spring Batch comes to mind, but I'm not clear on what exactly you're trying to do.  Are you trying to put a service layer in front of a batch process?

Comment: Please be more specific. First, what platform is this for? Java? .NET? Also, be more specific about what sort of work you want batched. Is the client sending you a batch of requests, or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer is to use a use a maxoccurrence unbounded setting so that you'll get an array of objects.

Comment: you still haven't said what platform you're talking about.